# Running parallel test in Local Machine

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I have some selenium tests. Those are code with the base of selenium API version 2.33. Those are running in my Windows 7 machine with IE7(9 compatible mode ). I just want to run them in parallel in my local machine itself. With a use of TestNG xml i tried to run them in parallel. It works only few steps then get stuck up somewhere. It throws some random timeout errors in either of the test cases. But they runs perfectly in individual. i just want to confirm whether this is a good idea of running them in parallel, or i need to do some code enhancement to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run multiple Instances of IE on the same machine. IEDriver has window focus issues as it uses native support offered by Windows to perform events that require window to be on foreground. As of now, you can only have 1 IE per machine.

Comment: Can i achieve it if i can have two displays?

Comment: Yeah you can. Use VMs if you can.

Comment: Let me test and will post you.

Comment: Yeah I would also suggest using VMs - with a CI like Jenkins.

Comment: VMs and [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) are the way to go;  You never want the possibility of having your tests fail because of weirdo interactions between browser instances, and Selenium Grid lets you run tests without having to have your testing framework aware of the address of your VMs.  Plus it makes parallelisation easier to extend.